# Gamma(1,1/θ) interchangeable with exp(1/θ) and exp(θ)?

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

Am I correct that the probability density function:

$f(x;\theta)=\theta e^{-\theta x}$

is $Gamma(1, 1/\theta)$ or $exp(1/θ)$ or $exp(θ)$ ?

They all have the same distribution?

Comment: It depends on which parameterization you're talking about. in each case. See the wikipedia page for the gamma distribution where it shows two different parameterizations (shape-rate and shape-scale). There's a third parameterization common when using the gamma in GLMs, a shape-mean parameterization (and indeed the actual exponential-family glm formulation in terms of mean-dispersion).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right.

If $X\sim\Gamma(1,\frac{1}{\theta})$ (with a shape-scale parametrization, not a shape-rate parametrization) then

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\Gamma{(1)}\frac{1}{\theta}}x^{(1-1)}e^{-x\theta}=\theta e^{-\theta x}$

This is the exponential distribution $exp(\theta)$, you need take care of your parameter's form whether it is $\theta$ or $\frac{1}{\theta}$

Note: $\Gamma(1)=(1-1)!=1$